# Atomic file copy in C on Linux (replace a file with a new version and keep a copy of the old version)

Tags: c, linux, rename, system-calls, atomic

I'm trying to implement an atomic version of copy on write. I have certain conditions if met that will make a copy of the original file.

I implemented something like this pseudo code.

```
//write operations//
if(some condition)
   //create a temp file//
   rename(srcfile, copied-version)
   rename(tmpfile, srcfile)
```

problem with this logic :

Hardlinks.
I want to transfer the Hardlink from copied version to new srcfile.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Hardlinks are one directional pointers.  So you can't modify or remove other hardlinks that you don't explicitly know about.  All you can do is write to the same file data, and that's not atomic.

This rule applies uniformly to both hadlinks and [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).  What that means is that you can't modify the content pointed to by an unknown hardlink and *not* modify the content pointed to by another process with the same file open.

That effectively prevents you from modifying the file an unknown hardlink points
to atomically.

---

If you have control over every process which might modify or access these files (if they are only modified by programs you've written), then you might be able to use [flock()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) to signal to other processes that the file is in use.  This won't work if the file is stored on an NFS remote file system, but should generally work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, *file leases* can be a solution to the underlying issue – ensuring atomic content updates – but only if each reader and writer opens and closes the file for each snapshot.

Because a similar limitation happens for the traditional copy–update–rename-over sequence, perhaps the file lease solution would also work for OP.

For details, see [man 2 fcntl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) *Leases* and *Managing signals* sections.  The process must either have the same owner as the file, or have the [CAP_LEASE](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) capability (usually granted to the process via filesystem capabilities).  Superuser processes (running as root) have the capability by default.

The idea is that when the process wishes to make "atomic" changes to the file, it acquires a write lease on the file. *This only succeeds if no other process has the file open.* If another process tries to open the file, the lease holder receives a signal, and has up to lease-break-time (about a minute, typically) to downgrade the lease (or simply close the file); during that time, the opener will block.

Note that there is no way to divert the opener.  The situation is that the opener already has a handle to the underlying inode (so access checks and filename resolution has already occurred); it is just that kernel won't return it to the userspace process before the lease is released or broken.

Your lease owner can, however, create a copy of the current contents to a temporary file, acquiring a write lease on that as well, and then rename it over the target file name.  This way, each (set of) opener(s) obtain a handle to the file contents as they were at the time of the opening; if they do any modifications, they will be "private", and not reflected on the original file. Since the underlying inode is no longer referred to by any filename, when they (the last process having it open) close it, the inode is deleted and the storage released back to the file system.  The Linux page cache also caches such accesses very well, so in many cases the "temporary copy file" never even hits actual storage media (unless there is memory pressure, i.e. memory needed for non-pagecache purposes).

A pure "atomic modification" does not require any kind of copies or renames, only holding the lease for the duration of the set of writes that must appear atomic for the readers.

Note that taking a write lease will normally block until no other process has the file open any longer, so the time at which such a lease-based atomic update can occur, is restricted, and not guaranteed to be always available. (For example, you may have a lazy process that just keeps the file open, and occasionally polls it.  If you have such processes, this lease-based approach won't work – but nor would the copy–rename-over approach either.)

Also, leases work only on local files.

If you need record-based atomicity, just use fcntl-based record locks, and have all readers take a read-lock for the region they want to access atomically, and all writers take a write-lock for the region to be updated, as record-locks are advisory (i.e., do not block reads or writes, only other record locks).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to transfer the Hardlink

That's not how hardlinks work.  They're not links between directory entries, they're links from pathnames to inodes.  Unless you know which other directory entries are links to this inode (and can change them too to point to a new inode), you're going to have to modify the file contents of that existing inode.  Philip's answer explains the same thing.

---

Your logic also doesn't atomically replace `srcfile`.  Between `rename` calls, there's no `srcfile`.

**If you didn't have the impossible hardlink requirement**, use [Linux `renameat2`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) with `RENAME_EXCHANGE` to swap an newly-written file with the original srcfile.

Or with just portable POSIX calls, `link()` `srcfile` to `copied-version`, then `rename` the `tmpfile` to `srcfile` to atomically replace it, so there's never an instant where another process could get `ENOENT` on `srcfile`.